# Is there any client side method in linux to access blocked website by ISP?

Tags: linux

Some ISPs block access to some website because of political policies. Is there a method in linux that can bypass connection to websites using ssl without ISPs acknowledged?
I don't want to use a VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this!
https://github.com/SadeghHayeri/GreenTunnel

It worked for me, I live in Iran and it works for most of the ISPs, also I got positive feedback from a number of people in Turkey and Russia.
The regime does not have ability to censor IP layer (3) packets (for example Google.com and Youtube.com have a same IP address, and they can’t block YouTube without blocking google search!)

They use DPI (deep packet inspection) to reed layer 4 data transmitted and try to block some traffics. GreenTunnel try to bypass this kind of firewalls! For example they search for HTTP like packets to found which website try to riches. But their services have some bugs! For example they try to find ‘host: ... ‘ header in HTTP packets, what what happened if we change it to hOsT?! Maybe it bypasses DPI!
Or in HTTPS they use SNI field to found websites, but if we send fragmented IP packets they must make their tools to State-Full services and save all fragments to parse packet and found SNI field which will cost them a lot of money to make them in trouble!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It also worked for me for https website.